# Where can I get the mxml for the default skins of spark components?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm skinning a lot of components lately and spend a lot of time building them up from scratch only so I can make some small changes from the default.

Are mxml files for the default skins available anywhere so that I can just copy/paste then edit to save time?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out myself, you can find the original skins in the sdk at the following location:

frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/skins/spark

Would still like to know if they are published anywhere on the web though.